# Two lines from different dataframes in seaborn's facetgrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`... I need to plot two lines coming from each dataframe in the same plot. I've been able to plot the one line, but I don't know how to plot the second line...I have:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df1, col="S")
g.map(sns.lineplot, "Q", "M")
```

How do I add a second line (which is on the same scale) but coming from `df2`, to `g`?

Comment: The recommended seaborn way, is to concatenate the dataframes, adding a new column which indicates the source.  And then use `hue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a unique frame id field to each frame and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them. Pass the frame id to `hue` parameter of `FacetGrid`.

#### Example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Q': np.arange(10),
                    'M': np.random.randn(10),
                    'S': np.random.choice([1, 2], 10)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Q': np.arange(10),
                    'M': np.random.randn(10),
                    'S': np.random.choice([1, 2], 10)})

data = pd.concat([df1.assign(frame='df1'),
                  df2.assign(frame='df2')])

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="S", hue='frame')
g.map(sns.lineplot, "Q", "M")
plt.legend()
```

[out]

[image]